# How to fix a validation error within a <script> tag

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have an HTML page that's giving a validation error.  Here's the section of the code producing the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
(multiple HTML statements)
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
          coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.maxHeight){
              content.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
              content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            } 
          });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

When the page is validated I get the errors:

```
Line 209 - character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data
Line 209 - StartTag: invalid element name
```

I understand that it's referring to the LESS THAN character in the FOR statement.
How do I show a Less Than symbol (<) without producing a validation error?

Comment: Try with &lt; instead of <

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried that earlier and again just now.  The validation errors go away, but I get a warning that my code might not work.  Sure enough, the functionality doesn't work when the "<" symbol is replaced with the HTML code.

Comment: You have the string `(multiple HTML statements)` in your code. That could be contributing to your issues, since it's not valid HTML.